# MySQL Can you override a server SQL mode at the database level?

Tags: mysql, sql-mode

We have a single MySQL 5.7 server that we need to have in a non-strict mode because some legacy databases require it. However, in our newest app, we'd like the database to enforce strictness (especially `NO_ZERO_DATE`). Is there a way to override the server-level configurations at the database level?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the SQL mode by session with :

```
SET SESSION sql_mode = 'modes';
```

According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-setting) :

> Setting the SESSION variable affects only the current client.

This could be a workaround to solve your problem. I think there is no direct way to set the SQL mode by database.

Note also :

> **Important**
>
> SQL mode and user-defined partitioning.  Changing the server SQL mode after creating and inserting data into partitioned tables can cause major changes in the behavior of such tables, and **could lead to loss or corruption of data**. It is strongly recommended that you never change the SQL mode once you have created tables employing user-defined partitioning.

Maybe the safer way is to use two instances of MySQL server.

Comment: "Maybe the safer way is to use two instances of MySQL server." Oh yeah, that's certainly safer. Not sure it's an option, though